# Images scrolling up with fixed background

Tags: css, background, z-index

I've managed to get the images scrolling up but I lose my header (which I have placed as a background in the body tag) when scrolling down through the images.  It becomes a white background.

It also appears the images are scrolling above the header image.  I have the z-index setup in a way I thought would allow the header to always be on top.

https://jsfiddle.net/25xqL2ec/

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"><html>
<html>
<HEAD>
<style type="text/css">

body { background-image:url('http://lib.store.yahoo.net/lib/oberers-flowers/Background-2013.gif');
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
    z-index:3;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}


.bgimg-paisley {
    background-image:url('http://lib.store.yahoo.net/lib/oberers-flowers/black-paisley-background.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    position:fixed;
    top:97px;
    left:0px;
    min-width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    z-index:1;
}

.imgwedding {
    position:absolute;
    top:110px;
    left:200px;
    z-index:2;
    width:700px;
}

-->
</style>

</head>
<body>


<div class="bgimg-paisley"></div>

    <div class="imgwedding">
    <img border="0" src="http://lib.store.yahoo.net/lib/oberers-flowers/bride-and-bridesmaid.jpg">
    <div style="height:80px;"></div>

    <img border="0" src="http://lib.store.yahoo.net/lib/oberers-flowers/bride-and-bridesmaid.jpg">
    <div style="height:80px;"></div>
    <img border="0" src="http://lib.store.yahoo.net/lib/oberers-flowers/bride-and-bridesmaid.jpg">
    <div style="height:80px;"></div>
    <img border="0" src="http://lib.store.yahoo.net/lib/oberers-flowers/bride-and-bridesmaid.jpg">
    <div style="height:80px;"></div>
    <img border="0" src="http://lib.store.yahoo.net/lib/oberers-flowers/bride-and-bridesmaid.jpg">
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have your header as a `background-image` of your body...

Comment: yes but if I pull it out, I am somehow losing it altogether.  It just shows a white background. https://jsfiddle.net/7hv7wyf8/

Comment: Yes because `headerbody` has no content and has no dimensions set in css. so it is not displaying because it's 0x0 pixels

Comment: also, `z-index` only works with positioned elements. Meaning if you define a `z-index` on an element you have to set either `position:relative;` or `position:absolute;` or `position:fixed;` for the z-index to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make your header a separate element, like a `<header>` tag, and then you can set you background-image to that and set it `position:fixed;`

Your header needs to be a separate element because everything is nested in the `body`. Your background-image will scroll with your content unless you set its background-position to fixed, but even then it would not be on top of your content because its a background-image. z-index does not apply to background-images.

Update your HTML by adding a `<header>` element above `.bgimg-paisley` like this:

```
<header></header>
<div class="bgimg-paisley"></div>
...
```

Next update your css style for the `body`, by replacing the `body` selector with `header`, then add a `position:fixed;` style to fix it to the top and give it some dimensions since it has no content. Like this:

```
header { 
    background-image:url('http://lib.store.yahoo.net/lib/oberers-flowers/Background-2013.gif');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:3;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:97px;
}
```

See this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/25xqL2ec/1/) for a demo

Comment: That worked but if you could clarify.  You said it will always be behind the content as a background image but your example works with it being a background image on the header instead of body.  Is it which section that makes a difference?

Comment: It is a bit confusing I agree. The reason I said it would be behind the content is simply because it was set as the `background-image` of the `body` and all your content is inside the `body`. So content inside an element will always be on top of that elements `background-image`. Now that it is a separate element, and all your images are outside of the `header` you can stack them with `z-index`. Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I put a class images and set it to overflow:scroll and margin-left and right to auto to center it. I also set your top image to fixed.

```css
body {
  background-image: url('http://lib.store.yahoo.net/lib/oberers-flowers/Background-2013.gif');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: 3;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
.images {
  width: 800px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 800px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.bgimg-paisley {
  background-image: url('http://lib.store.yahoo.net/lib/oberers-flowers/black-paisley-background.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: fixed;
  top: 97px;
  left: 0px;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
.imgwedding {
  position: fixed;
  top: 110px;
  left: 200px;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 700px;
}
```

```html
<body>


  <div class="bgimg-paisley">

    <div id="imgwedding">


      <div class="images">
        <img border="0" src="http://lib.store.yahoo.net/lib/oberers-flowers/bride-and-bridesmaid.jpg">

        <img border="0" src="http://lib.store.yahoo.net/lib/oberers-flowers/bride-and-bridesmaid.jpg">
        <img border="0" src="http://lib.store.yahoo.net/lib/oberers-flowers/bride-and-bridesmaid.jpg">

        <img border="0" src="http://lib.store.yahoo.net/lib/oberers-flowers/bride-and-bridesmaid.jpg">

        <img border="0" src="http://lib.store.yahoo.net/lib/oberers-flowers/bride-and-bridesmaid.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>


</body>
```